# keyPressEvent() is not catching some keys on OSX

Tags: c++, qt, macos, keypress

I am writing a program in Qt c++ and I'm having some problem handling key press events. When run on Linux (Ubuntu 10.10) or Windows 7 the application catches these key events just fine. However when I run the program on OSX 10.6.7 it doesn't catch any character keys, number keys, or the arrow keys. It *does* catch the caps lock, command, option, control, shift (modifier keys), but nothing else.

Is there some kind of special case of OSX that I need to handle? Perhaps a configuration? or a signal i need to connect with?

TIA

Comment: Are you sure it's a not a focus or filtering problem? do you have a minimal test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the window's focus policy to get it to accept keys.

Something like this:

`QMainWindow.setFocusPolicy ( Qt::StrongFocus );`